# Retrieve data from different folders that are named sequentially

Tags: matlab, directory, sequential

I have several folders each named sequentially i.e. Center Left P1, Center Left P2 etc. Within each folder I have 38 ".dat" files which contain data that I want for analysis. Is it possible to create a Matlab script which will open each folder and retrieve the ".dat" files? Sorry I am relatively new to matlab and previously I have been manually naming each file in Matlab in order to get the data I need. But this would take too long in this case.
Regards,
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) command and [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) commands for this purpose.

```
myData = cell(1,numFolders);
for p=1:numFolders
    folderName = sprintf('Center Left P%d', p ); % current folder name
    %// working with relative paths. If abs paths are used, remove leading '.' 
    datFiles = dir( fullfile( '.',  folderName, '*.dat' ) ); %// should return a list of all dat files in specific folder
    myData{p} = cell( 1, numel(datFiles) );
    for di=1:numel(datFiles)
        myData{p}{di} = importdata( fullfile( '.', folderName, datFiles(di).name ) ); %// read data
    end
end
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that there is a sub folder within each folder called 0.66D. Ie the folder tree is like this, "Center Left P1"-"0.66D"-then the 38.dat files. How do I incorporate the second subfloder. Sorry for the inconvience.

Comment: @Jerry simply change the argument for the `dir` command that reads the `dat` files. Read the doc on `dir` and `fullfile`, all the info you need is there.

Comment: Hi Shai, I have been using the following code. It loads the .dat files from the first folder but it doesn't load any from the other subfolders. Any ideas? `clear
clc
for n = 1:20
foldername =  sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\Free run\\Center Left P%d\\0.66D', n);
datFiles = dir( fullfile( '.',  foldername, '*.dat' ) );
files = dir('*.dat');
for i=1:length(files)
    eval(['load ' files(i).name ' -ascii']);
end
end`

Comment: @Jerry why `datFiles` and `files`?

Comment: Sorry that was an error by me. My problem at the moment is that the code can find the files. `clear clc for n = 1:20 foldername = sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\Free run\\Center Left P%d\\0.66D', n);` even when I include the line `dir(foldername)` it lists all the files in the subfolder, including the .dat files. But when I try to load the individual .dat files it then claims that there are none. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @jerry Note that in my answer `folderName` is separated from the `'*.dat'` argument for `dir`. `fls=dir(...);` return the filename **without** its path. therefore you need `fullfile(foldername,fls(ii).name)` - to add the path to the filename.

Comment: Shai, When I run the following code `for n = 1:20
    foldername = sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\TSR7.85\\Center Left P%d\\0.66D', n)
    datFiles = dir( fullfile( '.',  foldername, '*.dat' ) )
end` I get the following error; `datFiles = 

0x1 struct array with fields:

    name
    date
    bytes
    isdir
    datenum` for some reason it won't list the .dat files in the subfolder. Any ideas?

Comment: Also I forgot to add that I get the same error when I run the code with `datFiles = fullfile( '.', foldername, '*.dat' )` instead of `datFiles = dir( fullfile( '.', foldername, '*.dat' ) )`

Comment: @Jerry you are working with absolute paths, remove the leading `'.'` from `fullfile` command.

Comment: I understand now. I have run the following `clear
clc
for n = 1:20
    foldername = sprintf('G:\\Protable Hard Drive\\PHD Hard Drive\\Experimental Data\\Bulkrename Trial\\TSR7.85\\Center Left P%d\\0.66D', n)
    dir(foldername)
    datfiles = dir( fullfile(foldername, '*.dat'))
    
end` and I get datfiles = 38x1 which is correct. But this is only for one subfolder. How do I get a list of all the .dat files. There should be 1502 of them. Regards, Jerry

Comment: Thanks for all the help Shia. I got it working. Just one more thing. When the data is imported it appears as one row in an array with the name of the array being the actual size of it. i.e. 1024x3. Is there a way that I can name these to reflect where they came from. For example if the first set of data came from the file ending in Center Left P1 then could I name the data Left P1?

Comment: @Jerry you can name the data using [struct](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html) with [dynamic field names](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/08/20/advanced-matlab-dynamic-field-names/).